# Automatically set product "in stock" after credit memo

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, stock, quantity

Is there a way to set the product's stock status automatically to "In Stock" after a credit memo has been created and quantity is restored?

Or would it somehow be possible to set that setting automatically to all products that has qty > 0?

Comment: Any movement on this? Anything I can do to help clarify an answer for you? Please update your question if you have more information that can help us close this out.

Comment: I still have no idea how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found an extension that fixes this issue. Seems to work also with 1.9.x editions when tested.

https://github.com/gsafcik/StockAvailability

Answer (score 3):

When you create the credit memo there is a field that allows the user to specify whether the item should be returned to stock:

[image]

In the case where more than one product was ordered it provides an input field that allows the admin to input the # of items from the credit memo that will be returned to stock.

Comment: You can set in the configuration if that checkbox is checked by default somewhere in System > Configuration > Inventory Configuration

Comment: What I meant was the stock availability setting in product's inventory tab that has options of "in stock" and "out of stock". Is that possible to be set to "in stock" somehow automatically after it has been automatically set to "out of stock" when product has been sold out? If you then create a credit memo, you have to manually find the product and set that setting "in stock".

Answer (score 1):

By default this isn't possible, Magento can only automatically change the product to out of stock. With some modification to the _beforeSave function in Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock_Item (overwrite the class with your own) it can.

Answer (score 0):

The same issue in Magento 2.4.3, does anyone have a solution?

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/195143)